# The inner product of the Cartesian Product space

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

I want to know how can one define the inner product in the Cartesian product of spaces, i.e. let $A,B$ two hilbert spaces.

Let $a_1, a_2 \in A$  and $b_1, b_2 \in B$, how can one express the inner product $\langle (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2) \rangle _{A \times B}$?

is it just the sum of the $A$ and $B$ products: $\langle (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2) \rangle _{A \times B}= \langle a_1 , a_2 \rangle_A + \langle b_1 ,b_2 \rangle_B$?

thank you, I will appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thank you... yes, I think I've found the answer here: https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Hilbert_Space_Direct_Sum

Answer (score 7):

One can check directly that setting
$$
\langle (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2) \rangle _{A \times B}= \langle a_1 , a_2 \rangle_A + \langle b_1 ,b_2 \rangle_B
$$
defines an inner product on $A\times B$. Linearity and switching properties are easy, and also that
$$
\langle (a,b),(a,b)\rangle_{A\times B}\ge0
$$
Now, suppose that $\langle (a,b),(a,b)\rangle_{A\times B}=0$. Then $\langle a,a\rangle_A+\langle b,b\rangle_B=0$, from which $a=0$ and $b=0$ follows.

The projection maps $p_A\colon A\times B\to A$ and $p_B\colon A\times B\to B$ are bounded (that is, continuous) and it's readily shown that this is a product in the sense that if we are given a Hilbert space $C$ and bounded linear maps $f_A\colon A\to C$, $f_B\colon B\to C$, there is a unique bounded linear map $g\colon A\times B\to C$ such that $f_A=p_A\circ g$ and $f_B=p_B\circ g$: just define
$$
g(a,b)=f_A(a)+f_B(b)
$$
and check boundedness.